# R shiny: Problems with fileInput in reactive function (ui not found)

Tags: r, shiny

I have build an app in shiny. it works sometimes, and it crashes sometimes and I have no idea of what to do.

Basically the idea of the app is to allow the user to upload an xlsx file. The app uses the algorithm and returns a table on the app.

Currently my problem is:

> Error in force(ui) : object 'ui' not found

the ui code is

```
    ui<- 
  fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Upload the list", accept = c(".xlsx"), buttonLabel = "Seach"),
      sliderInput("max", "max in groups:",  
                  min = 11, max = 17, value=14),
      sliderInput("min", "min in groups:",  
                  min = 5, max = 9, value=7))),
    mainPanel(
    tableOutput('grouped')
  ))

server <- function(input,output){

  dataInput <- reactive({

    func <- function (val,valm) {


      # ====
      # ====== input ==========
      inFile<- input$file
      library(readxl)
      library(plyr)
      ext <- "xlsx"
      file.rename(inFile$datapath,
                  paste(inFile$datapath, ext, sep="."))
      members <- read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ext, sep="."), 1)

      #members <- read_excel(inFile$datapath)
      members$free <- 0
      members$free2 <- 0
      members$free3 <- 0
      members$freeENG <- 0
      members$freeENG[members$`English Required` == "no"] <- 1

      #View(members)

      groups <- data.frame("Effective Communication"=character(20), 
                           "Decision Making and Problem Solving"= character(20), 
                           "Feedback Is a Gift"=character(20),
                           "Fierce Accountability"=character(20),
                           "ME During Change"=character(20),
                           "Assertiveness Training"=character(20),
                           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)




      i=1
      miss = TRUE
      missENG = TRUE
      ECG= matrix(c(1, "Effective.Communication"),nrow=1)
      DMG= matrix(c(1, "Decision.Making.and.Problem.Solving"),nrow=1)
      FBG= matrix(c(1, "Feedback.Is.a.Gift"),nrow=1)
      FAG= matrix(c(1,"Fierce.Accountability"),nrow=1)
      MEG= matrix(c(1, "ME.During.Change"),nrow=1)
      ASG= matrix(c(1, "Assertiveness.Training"),nrow=1)
      indexes <- rbind(ECG,DMG,FBG,FAG,MEG,ASG)

      # ===========
      max= val
      min= valm
```

It doest not finish where... there are several lines in the middle. but the end is:

```
      return(groups)  
    }

    func(input$max,input$min)})

  output$grouped <- renderTable({dataInput()}, spacing = 'xs', rownames= TRUE) 
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

As you can see I have build a function inside of the reactive that takes in the input$max and input$min together with the fileInput and then returs the "groups".
"groups" is then a table output.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you look at ui, you will see that there is a comma misplaced.

Comment: This just seems to be a syntax error. Are you sure you're not getting a different error message earlier in the process?

Comment: @MrFlick Thaanks! I completely forgot to check the earlier error messages.

I found out I had a problem with "buttonLabel = "Seach"" that wasnt being used. and then I also had to include the "mainpanel" inside the sidebarPanel.

Now works fine, thanks!